# Why is the line width of magnetic resonance proportional to the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics, spectroscopy

Alarn Corney states in his book "Atomic and Laser Spectroscopy", that with higher amplitude of the rf-field, the line width also rises. Why is that the case? [image: this]